# How do I update my server's kernel version

Tags: database, security, linux-kernel, kernel, root

I own a small web design and webhosting company.  Recently I have been attacked by hackers and want to update my kernel version so they couldn't exploit it via a local root. I work with a datacenter located in Arizona and would really like some help.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about Linux, usually the distribution will have a mechanism for updating the OS, including security patches to the kernel. It should not be necessary to recompile the kernel separately. What distro are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the kind of question for stackoverflow. Anyway. You have to:

1. download the kernel source from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/)
2. configure the kernel with `make menuconfig` or `make xconfig`
3. compile the kernel with `make -j4` (where the option -j is the number of processor)
4. copy the kernel from `/arch/x86/boot/bzImage` to your boot directory (`/boot/`)
5. add a new option in your boot loader to boot the system with the new kernel